# Do we have or need a dictionary of puzzle terms?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This question was inspired by posting "[Assumption Needed when Solving Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5937/assumption-needed-when-solving-puzzle)".

I was wondering if it would be worthwhile to have a collection of typical terms used for puzzling (and on site). And if so, how this should exist.

- as a Question post ?
- as a site-Wiki ?

To a certain extent, the tags and the tag-wiki fulfil this requirement, but having all puzzle-terms being tags seems to be a really bad idea. On the other hand, right now we tend to link to other Wikipedia articles quite often, and it might be a good thing to have a "puzzler's dictionary" at hand. After all, speaking a common language helps communication.

I was first wondering if I should ask this "What terms do we need for puzzles?" question on the main site as a puzzle-related question, but I think there might be better ways to do this...

Comment: There is the [Help section](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help) which seems like the most obvious place for this. The question there is "Can we customise it enough to have a section just for terms we want to formalise?"